# select difference of max weight ,minimum weight having last name is Maroni

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

```
SELECT weight AS weight_delta
from (select max(weight) 
      from patients 
      where last_name='Maroni')
      -
      (select min(weight) 
      from patients 
      where last_name='Maroni');
```

Answer (score 3):

You are thinking too complex. The difference can be found without any subqueries:

```
SELECT MAX(weight) - MIN(weight) AS weight_delta 
FROM patients WHERE last_name = 'Maroni';
```